# Battery is always 100% while charging

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, battery, nokia-lumia-735

I have a Nokia Lumia 735. When I connect the phone to charger the battery status changes to 100% every time. If i restart my phone the battery status shows the real % change of battery. Whne I restart my phone when it is plugged into power,the battery status changes back to 100% in little time after restart. How fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably your battery. I would like to think its damaged and it needs replacement.

However, to be very sure that this is a battery issue, and not a system one, do a soft reset and see if anything changes. Don't worry, soft resets do not clear data or delete the files you need on your phone. They're safe.

Whilst your phone is on:

> Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the "slide down to power off" screen.

Try connecting the charger after your phone powers on and see what is indicated. If the problem is not resolved then yes, its a battery issue. You might need to switch in another battery and see